# Why aren't my models linking?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to link two (and more) models in a CakePHP application.

I have two database tables: `clients` and `notes`. I have the following model classes:

```
<?php
class Client extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Client';
    var $hasMany = 'Note';
}
```

And:

```
<?php
class Note extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Note';
    var $belongsTo = 'Client';
}
```

However, I don't think they're linking. When I run `print_r($this->Client->find());` in a controller I get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [Client] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Martin Bean
        )

)
```

How can I also fetch the associated `Note` records for each `Client`?

**EDIT:** Despite having the above in my model classes, if I place the following in a controller:

```
$this->Client->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
print_r($this->Client->find('all', array('contain' => 'Note')));
```

I get the following error message:

> Warning (512): Model "Client" is not associated with model "Note" [CORE/cake/libs/model/behaviors/containable.php, line 363]

Have I missed something that isn't explained in the CakePHP cookbook?

**EDIT 2:** I don't know if this is any help; it's the debug output:

> ContainableBehavior::containments() -
>   CORE/cake/libs/model/behaviors/containable.php, line 363
>   ContainableBehavior::beforeFind() -
>   CORE/cake/libs/model/behaviors/containable.php, line 121
>   ModelBehavior::dispatchMethod() -
>   CORE/cake/libs/model/model_behavior.php, line 169
>   BehaviorCollection::trigger() -
>   CORE/cake/libs/model/model_behavior.php, line 494 Model::find() -
>   CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 2108 PostsController::index() -
>   APP/controllers/posts_controller.php, line 6 Dispatcher::_invoke() -
>   CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 204 Dispatcher::dispatch() -
>   CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 171 [main] - APP/webroot/index.php,
>   line 83

Comment: Try clearing your model cache as well `APP/tmp/cache/models` - especially if you added these changes after initially creating and running these files. Sometimes it's all it takes ~

Comment: Also check your (app_)model for any trace of `$this->recursive` - if it's less than 0 you won't get related data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! My models' filenames were incorrect.

Instead of `client.php` or `note.php` I had saved them as `client_model.php` and `note_model.php`. All works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

So just to confirm

You have two tables 'notes' and 'clients'

Both have a primary key named id

'notes' contains 'client_id'

There is correct test data, 'client' with id 1 is on several 'note' rows

Before your find() call there is not a $this->Client->recursive = -1 assignment.

Add

$var  actsAs = array('Containable');

to both your Client and Note model or just add it to your app_model.php to attach the containable behaviour to every model automatically.

P.S Set debug to 2 to clear our the model cache if you have recently added a new table or amended a field.

Comment: That's correct. I've set debug level to 2, flushed the cache, and added the `$actsAs` declaration to `app_model.php` (which I moved to my `app/models/` directory, yet still getting the `Model "Client" is not associated with model "Note"` error message.

Comment: Have you dropped the attach behaviour call? This is perculiar

Comment: I've dumped the contents of my controller and related models here: https://gist.github.com/1103085. Hopefully this can show any problems.

Answer (score 0):

look up containable. $this->Client->find('all', array('contain' => array('Note')));

Comment: are these models in a plugin by chance?

Comment: if containable is saying that, either the files are named incorrectly or some permissions error. cake will create model instances on the fly without a file and seems what the problem is here. do pr(get_class($this->Client)) and it will say AppModel. then you know the above is true. if that says Client maybe the Note is the problem